# Cross-compilation using clang and libc++ instead gcc and libstdc++

Tags: c++, gcc, rust, clang, libc++

I use Rust on Linux and want to cross-compile my project to ARM. I did this before using `gcc` libs and it worked fine:

```sh
apt-get -y install gcc-aarch64-linux-gnu g++-aarch64-linux-gnu
export TARGET=aarch64-unknown-linux-gnu
rustup target add ${TARGET}
cargo build --target ${TARGET} --manifest-path my-app/Cargo.toml
```

Now, my goal is to use `clang` compiler and `libc++` lib instead of `libstdc++`. Is there a way to achieve this?

If I install:

```sh
apt-get install gcc-aarch64-linux-gnu g++-aarch64-linux-gnu clang libc++-dev
```

And specify:

```sh
export CXXFLAGS=-stdlib=libc++ CC=clang CXX=clang++
```

It's failed.

```
  running "clang" "-O0" "-ffunction-sections" "-fdata-sections" "-fPIC" "-g" "-fno-omit-frame-pointer" "--target=aarch64-unknown-linux-gnu" "-I" "include" "-Wall" "-Wextra" "-std=c1x" "-Wbad-function-cast" "-Wnested-externs" "-Wstrict-prototypes" "-pedantic" "-pedantic-errors" "-Wall" "-Wextra" "-Wcast-align" "-Wcast-qual" "-Wconversion" "-Wenum-compare" "-Wfloat-equal" "-Wformat=2" "-Winline" "-Winvalid-pch" "-Wmissing-field-initializers" "-Wmissing-include-dirs" "-Wredundant-decls" "-Wshadow" "-Wsign-compare" "-Wsign-conversion" "-Wundef" "-Wuninitialized" "-Wwrite-strings" "-fno-strict-aliasing" "-fvisibility=hidden" "-fstack-protector" "-g3" "-DNDEBUG" "-c" "-o/builds/Zwje-UWj/0/my-project/shared-components/gateway/my-app/target/aarch64-unknown-linux-gnu/debug/build/ring-5811d32b218e60b7/out/aes_nohw.o" "crypto/fipsmodule/aes/aes_nohw.c"
  In file included from crypto/fipsmodule/aes/aes_nohw.c:15:
  In file included from include/GFp/aes.h:52:
  In file included from include/GFp/base.h:66:
  In file included from /usr/lib/llvm-7/lib/clang/7.0.1/include/stdint.h:61:
  /usr/include/stdint.h:26:10: fatal error: 'bits/libc-header-start.h' file not found
  #include <bits/libc-header-start.h>
           ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
  1 error generated.
  thread 'main' panicked at 'execution failed', /usr/local/cargo/registry/src/github.com-1ecc6299db9ec823/ring-0.16.20/build.rs:656:9
  note: run with `RUST_BACKTRACE=1` environment variable to display a backtrace
warning: build failed, waiting for other jobs to finish...
error: build failed
```

Although, without cross-compilation, with simple:

```sh
cargo build --manifest-path my-app/Cargo.toml
```

It works.

Comment: Rust doesn't use C++ libraries. Do you have a dependency on something that does, and if so, what is it? When you say, "it failed", what was the output?

Comment: @ColonelThirtyTwo, yes, subproject written in cpp. The error: https://pastebin.com/sAjYmhAk

Comment: Please edit the error message into the question.

Comment: Can you cross-compile just the C++ project with clang?

Comment: Aren't you missing a sysroot? That error seems like it may be due to clang using the build platform headers to cross compile, but you need it to use the headers for the host platform.
(EDIT: reversed terminology :P)

Comment: Here's some reading material that might help you out: https://clang.llvm.org/docs/CrossCompilation.html